# Axios POST request is complaining about cross origin, but curl request works fine

Tags: reactjs, axios

```
 let url = 'http://localhost:4001/api/v1/sessions/new';
      axios.post(url, data)
        .then(function(resp) {
          console.log('resp returned is ' + JSON.stringify(resp));
        });
```

I see this error in chrome console"

> Failed to load http://localhost:4001/api/v1/sessions/new: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4044' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

If I just try and curl the exact same API call it works fine:

```
curl -d "email=hello@asdf.com&password=hello123" -X POST http://localhost:4001/api/v1/sessions/new

{"apiResponse":{"success":true,"errors":[]}}
```

Why does it work with CURL but not with axios?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anything that isn't running in a browser doesn't care about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). If you'd like your web app to make requests to your server add the [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header to your server's response with the most permissive value being `*`:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

Comment: My server is responding with this `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`  My other API calls work fine, is there a way to debug what axios is seeing?

Comment: Look at the network tab in devtools. Also Axios sends json by default and your curl command is not sending json.

Comment: I see the access control is there in the request in chrome devtools network tab: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`

Comment: There isn't really a way for me to tell what's happening on your server. What you can do is in the network tab, right click one of the requests that's failing and go to Copy -> Copy as cURL. Paste it in your terminal and compare to the cURL command that is working.